# How to completely disable selinux policy check while building AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

sometimes the selinux policy is too complicated and fix the problem is time wasting
its not my concern

so how to completely disable selinux policy check while building AOSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS in your device config. So your private sepolicy will not be compiled.

Comment: Many Thanks
comment out *_SEPOLICY_DIRS vars in BoardConfigCommon.mk

Answer (score 0):

Set selinux kernel argument to permissive

Source: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#switching_to_permissive